# Strange Runtime Exception

Tags: codenameone

I recently deleted my Netbeans Cache folder (/appdata/local/netbeans/cache/) and my codenameone apps that make use of the native google maps plugin have been acting up. I get a runtime exception at startup. Below is the stacktrace.

I have removed cn1 plugin from NB, downloaded new copy of the native maps cn1lib, cleaned and built and i still get the same error... please help.

```
[EDT] 0:0:4,404 - Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - Could not initialize class com.codename1.impl.javase.StubLocationManager
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getLocationManager(JavaSEPort.java:8945)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.getLocationManager(Display.java:3573)
    at com.labafrique.creporter.MyApplication.writeLocation(MyApplication.java:2544)
    at com.labafrique.creporter.MyApplication.lambda$null$0(MyApplication.java:151)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1298)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1242)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1130)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
    at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:83)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.LocationSimulation.unitActionPerformed(LocationSimulation.java:609)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.LocationSimulation.access$1900(LocationSimulation.java:40)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.LocationSimulation$20.actionPerformed(LocationSimulation.java:446)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1258)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:622)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.LocationSimulation.setMeasUnit(LocationSimulation.java:729)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.StubLocationManager.<init>(StubLocationManager.java:78)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.StubLocationManager.<clinit>(StubLocationManager.java:58)
    ... 9 more
com.codename1.io.websocket.WebSocket$WebSocketException: Exception occurred while trying to connect.
    at com.codename1.io.websocket.WebSocket.connect(WebSocket.java:416)
    at com.codename1.io.websocket.WebSocket.access$400(WebSocket.java:39)
    at com.codename1.io.websocket.WebSocket$4.run(WebSocket.java:393)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketException: Failed to connect to 'localhost:9494': Connection refused: connect
    at com.codename1.io.websocket.WebSocketNativeImplImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.codename1.io.websocket.WebSocket.connect(WebSocket.java:405)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketException: Failed to connect to 'localhost:9494': Connection refused: connect
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.SocketConnector.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.SocketConnector.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocket.connect(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    ... 8 more
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.codename1.impl.javase.StubLocationManager
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getLocationManager(JavaSEPort.java:8945)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.getLocationManager(Display.java:3573)
    at com.labafrique.creporter.MyApplication.writeLocation(MyApplication.java:2544)
    at com.labafrique.creporter.MyApplication.lambda$null$0(MyApplication.java:151)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1298)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1242)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1130)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.codename1.impl.javase.StubLocationManager
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This started happening to one other user I'm aware of (but not to everyone surprisingly) as a result of the change to remove the maps in location manager. We had to remove them as Google became far too strict with maps key generation strategies.

We have a fix for this and will post it later on today or tomorrow morning.